# MotionEvent Android

Tags: android

I have this following code:

```
ListView s1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_contas);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COUNTRIES);
s1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This code shows my array of Countries, But what I am trying to do is when the user Touch and press down a country then I start a new Activity.

The process to start a new activity is ok for me, but my problem is the touch and press down.

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ListView`'s `setOnItemClickListener` to do what you need to when clicked:

```
s1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id){
      // Start your Activity according to the item just clicked.
      Log.d(TAG, "Item " +position+ " was clicked");
    }
  };)
```